# Start page Ubuntu

Tags: firefox

if you set the startpage of Firefox to about:startpage (or http://start.ubuntu.com) you get this: 
[image]

If you use http://start.ubuntu.com/current/Yahoo/ you get this:
[image]

Is it possible to use other search engines in the Ubuntu start page. I'm particularly interested in [DuckDuckGo.com](http://www.duckduckgo.com).

Comment: I abuse the app [InstantFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/instantfox/). Just delete every entry and add to "Standard search without shortcuts" my customized duckduckgo line. You can go to [here](https://duckduckgo.com/settings), change what you want and create a url at bottom by pressing "Bookmarklet and settings data". This url you just have to put in addressbar and replace an arbitrary search string with `%q`. Now you can search directly from addressbar what is very handsome in combination with the [!BANGS](https://duckduckgo.com/bang.html)... I NEVER WANT TO MISS THAT!

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a "Home Page" option but they rearranged the peferences configuration and it is now buried somewhere.
Type in the url field `about:config`, locate setting `browser.startup.homepage` and set its value to `https://duckduckgo.com/`. You will use the search engine directly, without your searches going through the ubuntu servers.

Comment: Well, on Firefox you just have to click the menubar (3 horizontal lines) and then settings > general

Answer (score 1):

You can download the page HTML I just wrote for you and set it as an offline startpage :

[image: ddg]

Copy-paste the following code in a text-file you'll name " *startpage.htm* " :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<title>Ubuntu Start Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: white;
    font-family: ubuntu, ubuntubeta, 'Bitstream Vera Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    /* fix buttons in FF */
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    /* Remove button margin in webkit */
    button{
        margin: 0;
    }
}   
.search-box {
    width: 595px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 63px;
}
.ubuntu-branding {
    background: url(http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -251px;
    background-color: #aea79f;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-top: 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.wrapper h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.logo a {
    font-size: 1px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url(http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/sprite.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: -10px -95px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 18px;
    width: 167px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper input {
    /* allows styling in webkit */
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 384px;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #AEA79F;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 65px auto 100px auto;
}
.inner form {
    height: 32px;
}
.external-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.external-links li {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 8px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.external-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: gray;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 40px;
}
.external-links a::after {
    content: " ›";
    font-size: 16px;
}
.external-links a:hover {
    color: #e24912;
}
.help-link, 
.shop-link, 
.community-link {
    background: url(http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/sprite.png) no-repeat;
}
.help-link {
    background-position: -10px -450px;
}
.help-link:hover {
    background-position: -10px -490px;
}
.shop-link {
    background-position: -10px -368px;
}
.shop-link:hover {
    background-position: -10px -410px;
}
.community-link {
    background-position: -10px -528px;
}
.community-link:hover {
    background-position: -10px -568px;
}
button {
    margin: 0 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: default;
    height: 32px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-box">
        <div class="ubuntu-branding"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="inner">
                <a href="https://duckduckgo.com/"><img src="https://duckduckgo.com/assets/logo_header.v103.min.svg"></a></h1>
<iframe src="http://duckduckgo.com/search.html" style="overflow:hidden;margin:0;padding:0;width:408px;height:40px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="external-links">
            <li class="help-link"><a href="https://help.ubuntu.com/">Ubuntu help</a></li>
            <li class="shop-link"><a href="http://shop.ubuntu.com/">Ubuntu shop</a></li>
            <li class="community-link"><a href="http://www.ubuntu.com/community">Ubuntu community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- close search-box -->    
</body></html>
```

This is exactly the same HTML code than the official Start Page, but I replaced Yahoo by DuckDuckGo + a logo.

You can also host it somewhere if you want and set that website as start-page, it's exactly the same.